# Do we have a way to implement face detection and recognition offline on browser?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, face-detection, face-recognition, dlib

I need to find a way to implement face detection and recognition completely offline using a browser. Trained model specific to each user maybe loaded initially. We only need to recognize one face per device. What is the best way to implement this?

I tried `tracking.js` to implement face detection. It works. But couldn't get a solution to implement recognition. I tried [face-recognition.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-recognition.js/). But it needs a node server.

Comment: I think you are looking for tensorflow.js

Comment: Is there a pre-trainer face recognizer model or where should I start?

Comment: I've never used tensorflow but I'm pretty sure you can train and deploy.

Comment: Where to get some examples?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at: [face-api.js](https://itnext.io/face-api-js-javascript-api-for-face-recognition-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-bcc2a6c4cf07) it can both detect and recognize faces in realtime completely in the browser! It's made by Vincent Mühler, the same creator of face-recognition.js.

([Face-api.js Github](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js?files=1))

Thing to note:

- It's realtime, my machine gets ~50ms (using MTCNN model)
- It's JavaScript but uses WebGL GPU acceleration under the hood which is why it performs so well
- It can also work on mobile! (tested on my S8+)
- I recommend looking at the included **examples** as well, these helped me a lot

I have used the package to create a working project, it was surprisingly easier than I thought and this is coming from a student that just started web development. (used it in a ReactJs App)

Just like you I was searching and trying things such as tracking.js but to be honest they didn't work well.

Comment: I have also made a list with a few selling points that I made for my coworkers: [https://justpaste.it/6e9r6](https://justpaste.it/6e9r6), it may give you some more insight